# How can I make a power system efficient and safe?

Tags: power-supply, transistors, circuit-design, power-electronics, circuit-protection

I am currently designing a power system and so far I have been using fuses before relays to protect against high current. Those relays lead to multiple loads to power. I was thinking of adding a Bypass capacitor to shunt noise entering the system, but I am lost on what to choose to control my current inflow to those relays and loads.

It is my first time  ever designing a schematic myself and I have been trying to read about ways to make it safe, but I am rather confused.

To sum up, my sub-questions are:

- Can I use a resistor before a fuse to control current inflow?
- Is there another way than using a resistor that could limit high power dissipation?
- What else should I think of when designing a power system?

The circuit will be connected to a current/voltage sensor and a microcontroller.

Comment: Please provide a schematic

Comment: Fuses don't protect against current spikes, they protect against sustained overcurrent. (Sustained for how long? that is the difference between fast and slow fuses; see their respective datasheets. Filters, common mode chokes, reservoir capacitors, can provide protection against current spikes; transient suppressors, varistors, zener diodes can protect against voltage spikes. With no specific requirements and no schematic that's about all you can expect.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Thank you

Answer (score 4):

1. Fuses are intended for short-circuit protection only.
2. A standard mains filter would take care of electrical noise.
3. Heat dissipated by a load is inherent and cannot be avoided by a series resistor but only taken over by it.